# Toggle Identify with Button

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am attempting to set up an Identify button that will only allow the identify functionality to be performed when the button is pressed.  I have gotten to the point that the identify only works when the button has been pushed the first time but I can't seem to turn the button off.  I have pasted a few bits of code below or you can follow the link to see the entire thing.

http://geoville.org/viewers/PopUp/

**Funtion to activate Identify**

```
function activateIdentify(){
    if (dijit.byId("tool_identify").checked) {
        dojo.connect(map, "onClick", executeIdentifyTask);
    }
  }
```

**Button to Activate function**

```
<div dojoType="dijit.form.ToggleButton" id="tool_identify" iconClass="dijitCheckBoxIcon" onClick="activateIdentify();" >Identify</div>
```

**Function to toggle buttons**

```
function toggleButtonIcon(tool) {

    //only the tools in the toolbar are dijit togglebuttons so can iterate thru them
    dijit.registry.byClass("dijit.form.ToggleButton").forEach(function(togbtn) {
      if (togbtn == tool) {
        togbtn.attr("checked", true);
      }
      else {
        togbtn.attr("checked", false);
      }
    });
  }  //end toggleButtonIcon
```

Thanks for your help.

-Mike

Comment: I have asked a new question here.

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11527/toggle-toolbar-button-and-activate-identify

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mike,

Set a global variable to hold the "onClick" listener, then disable the listener when the button is disabled.

```
var identifyListener;

function activateIdentify(){
  if (dijit.byId("tool_identify").checked) {
    identifyListener = dojo.connect(map, "onClick", executeIdentifyTask);
  } else {
    dojo.disconnect(identifyListener);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Lead, your code solved exactly what I asked for.  In the long run I am attempting to integrate an "Identify" button into the Esri Navtoolbar sample by using multiple toggle buttons.  Most of the code samples I find just seem overly complex.  Any suggestions on how to integrate the added block of code with your previous suggestion.  I have also updated the sample at the link.  http://geoville.org/viewers/PopUp/