# Toggle Toolbar Button and Activate Identify

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I already asked how to toggle an identify button in [Toggle Identify with Button](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11374), and was given the correct answer to the question, but when I tried to implement it into a toolbar that would disable the identify button when another button was pressed it didn't work.

I am hoping that soneone will be able to help put the two pieces of code together.  An example can be found at the following link and my code is below.

http://geoville.org/viewers/PopUp/

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
    <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples 
      on iOS devices-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Identify with Popup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/2.3/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/2.3/js/esri/dijit/css/Popup.css">
    
    <style>
      html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      .esriScalebar{
        padding: 20px 20px;
      }
      #map{
        padding:0;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">var dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true};</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=2.3"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
      dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
      dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
      dojo.require("esri.map");
      dojo.require("esri.dijit.Popup");
      dojo.require("esri.toolbars.navigation");
      dojo.require("dijit.Toolbar");

      
      var map, navToolbar;
      var resizeTimer;
      var identifyTask, identifyParams, identifyListener;
      
      function init() {
        var initExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent({"xmin":-9270392,"ymin":5247043,"xmax":-9269914,"ymax":5247401,"spatialReference":{"wkid":102100}});
        
        //setup the popup window 
        var popup = new esri.dijit.Popup({
          fillSymbol: new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([255,0,0]), 2), new dojo.Color([255,255,0,0.25]))
        }, dojo.create("div"));
   
        map = new esri.Map("map",{
          infoWindow:popup,
          extent:initExtent
        });
        
        dojo.place(popup.domNode,map.root);
        
        dojo.connect(map,"onLoad",mapReady);
        
        //Add the imagery layer to the map. View the ArcGIS Online site for services http://arcgisonline/home/search.html?t=content&f=typekeywords:service    
        var basemap = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer");
        map.addLayer(basemap);
        
        var landBaseLayer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/BloomfieldHillsMichigan/Parcels/MapServer",{opacity:.55});
        map.addLayer(landBaseLayer);
        
        navToolbar = new esri.toolbars.Navigation(map);
        //dojo.connect(navToolbar, "onExtentHistoryChange", extentHistoryChangeHandler);
      }
      
      
      
      //Sets up the ability for the buttons to be toggled.
        function toggleButtonIcon(tool) {
        //this toggles the button highlight in the toolbar to show which tool is currently active
        //note - doesn't do the FullExtent since it's a button not a togglebutton

        //only the tools in the toolbar are dijit togglebuttons so can iterate thru them
        dijit.registry.byClass("dijit.form.ToggleButton").forEach(function(togbtn) {
          if (togbtn == tool) {
            togbtn.attr("checked", true);
          }
          else {
            togbtn.attr("checked", false);
          }
        });
      }  //end toggleButtonIcon
    
    //This section gives the ability for the identify button to be toggled.
      function activateIdentify(){
        if (dijit.byId("identify").checked) {
            identifyListener = dojo.connect(map, "onClick", executeIdentifyTask);
        }
        else {
            dojo.disconnect(identifyListener);
        }
      }
      
      function mapReady(map){
       //map.infoWindow.resize(250,200);
       //dojo.connect(map,"onClick",executeIdentifyTask);
       
       //create identify tasks and setup parameters 
       identifyTask = new esri.tasks.IdentifyTask("http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/BloomfieldHillsMichigan/Parcels/MapServer");
       
       identifyParams = new esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters();
       identifyParams.tolerance = 3;
       identifyParams.returnGeometry = true;
       identifyParams.layerIds = [2];
       identifyParams.layerOption = esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters.LAYER_OPTION_VISIBLE;
       identifyParams.width  = map.width;
       identifyParams.height = map.height;

      
      //resize the map when the browser resizes - view the 'Resizing and repositioning the map' section in 
      //the following help topic for more details http://help.esri.com/EN/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp_start.htm#jshelp/inside_guidelines.htm
        dojo.connect(dijit.byId('map'), 'resize', function() {  //resize the map if the div is resized
          clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
          resizeTimer = setTimeout( function() {
            map.resize();
            map.reposition();
          }, 500);
        });
      }
      
   function executeIdentifyTask(evt) {
        identifyParams.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
        identifyParams.mapExtent = map.extent;
       
        var deferred = identifyTask.execute(identifyParams);

        deferred.addCallback(function(response) {    
          // response is an array of identify result objects    
          // Let's return an array of features.
          return dojo.map(response, function(result) {
            var feature = result.feature;
            feature.attributes.layerName = result.layerName;
            if(result.layerName === 'Tax Parcels'){
              //console.log(feature.attributes.PARCELID);
              var template = new esri.InfoTemplate("", "${Postal Address} <br/> Owner of record: ${First Owner Name}");
              feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
            }
            else if (result.layerName === 'Building Footprints'){
              var template = new esri.InfoTemplate("", "Parcel ID: ${PARCELID}");
              feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
            }
            return feature;
          });
        });

      
        // InfoWindow expects an array of features from each deferred
        // object that you pass. If the response from the task execution 
        // above is not an array of features, then you need to add a callback
        // like the one above to post-process the response and return an
        // array of features.
        map.infoWindow.setFeatures([ deferred ]);
        map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint);
      }
      
      dojo.addOnLoad(init);
    </script>
  </head>
  
  <body class="claro">

    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline'"  style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">
    <div id="header" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'" style="height:58px;text-align:left;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;color:#400D12;">
      <div id="navToolbar" data-dojo-type="dijit.Toolbar">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ToggleButton" id="zoomin"  data-dojo-props="iconClass:'zoominIcon', onClick:function(){navToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Navigation.ZOOM_IN);toggleButtonIcon(this);}">Zoom In</div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ToggleButton" id="zoomout" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'zoomoutIcon', onClick:function(){navToolbar.activate(esri.toolbars.Navigation.ZOOM_OUT);toggleButtonIcon(this);}">Zoom Out</div>
        <div dojoType="dijit.form.ToggleButton" id="identify" iconClass="dijitCheckBoxIcon" onClick="activateIdentify();toggleButtonIcon(this);" >Identify</div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" style="border:1px solid #000;padding:0;">
     </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add some additional logic to know what other buttons are activated  and toggle on and off as needed. Something like this:

```
    function updateTool(theDijit) {
        var zoominDij, zoomoutDij, panDij, idDij, itemArray;
        zoominDij = dijit.byId("zoomin");
        zoomoutDij = dijit.byId("zoomout");
        panDij = dijit.byId("pan");
        idDij = dijit.byId("identify");
        itemArray = [zoominDij, zoomoutDij, panDij, idDij];
        if (theDijit.attr("id") != "identify")
            identifyDisconnect();
        for (var i = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++) {
            if (theDijit.attr("id") == itemArray[i].attr("id")) {
                theDijit.attr("checked", true);
            } else {
                itemArray[i].attr("checked", false);
                itemArray[i].focus();
            }
        }
    }
```

You will need a little work on your itemArray to have the right button IDs as well as inside where you set the trigger to disable the other functions.

Coupled with a call like this on your toolbar buttons:

```
onclick="identifyConnect();updateTool(this);"
```

Now this additional call will set a value of what button was clicked, will help you disconnect the function from one and allow you to set active to the other. This is what I use on my productions sites like here [Washington State Sales Tax](http://dor.wa.gov/content/findtaxesandrates/salesandusetaxrates/lookupataxrate/).