# How to add an identify button with ArcGIS JS API?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

GIS StackExchange is the first website that I've come across that has come near to answering my question, but somehow I can't work the answer out in my head/or the answers here have confused things more.

I'd like to put a simple identify button on a web map. In simple terms, I want a map where the identify task is disconnected onload with an equally simple toggle on/off identify button.

I understand that you need to `dojo.disconnect` the onclick identify function and that you then need to `dojo.connect` it back in the onclick of a button but I can't work out how it all comes together. I've read and re-read the ArcGIS JavaScript API 'working with events' page but this too has lost me.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Do you have any code so we can see what is wrong?

Comment: code is good - please provide a link or source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best answer would be to look to this thread, it has a working sample of where you want to be going [Previous discussion on toolbar toggle](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11527/toggle-toolbar-button-and-activate-identify/11536#11536). 
You can see where he has a connection happening, the basic identify function, and then where you can toggle the connect/disconnect to get it working over and over.