# Create toggle buttons to activate individual query and identify tasks

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Can you please help with toggling query and identify tasks?
For example,
Parcel: button
Footpring: button
CIP: button

whenever one of the buttons is checked, all others are  inactive.

D.E.Wright provided a test link that is no longer active here: [Toggle Toolbar Button and Activate Identify](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11527/toggle-toolbar-button-and-activate-identify/19018#19018)

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: I am attempting to build a javascript api application that involves several functionalities: draw tools, query, find, etc. Now, whenever I click on the map it evokes the identify task, whether I want to or not. I would like to control when this task in called.

I am trying to figure out the best way to display all of my code for your viewing. I have an html file and a series of .js files along with the css.

Comment: could you please provide some example code, a test webpage or live page, as well as the tools you are using. Your tags are "arcgis" and "javascript" but you provided a link to a question that deals with "arcgis-server" and its relevant javascript api. Is this what you are working with?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to use dojo.connect to start a "listener" for the click, and use dojo.disconnect to switch the listener off again.

[This post](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp_start.htm#jshelp/inside_events.htm) is a little old but the principles remain:

```
var myOnClick_connect = dojo.connect(map, "onClick", myOnClickHandler);
dojo.disconnect(myOnClick_connect);
```

Switch on the Identify listener when you want to perform an identify, then switch it off when you switch on the Draw listener, etc. You could hook these functions up to buttons on a toolbar.